# Ordenar matriz de forma ascendente y descendente

Tags: java, array

tengo una duda acerca de ordenar una matriz de forma ascendente y descendente, he visto el método de la burbuja y también encontré algo sobre la función 'sort' pero no se como aplicarla, que debo saber sobre ella? llevo esto ahora ahora pero me tira error

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Matriz {
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x;
    int matriz[][];

    System.out.println("Ingrese la dimension de la matriz: ");
    x = sc.nextInt();
    matriz = new int[x][x];

    //Relleno de matriz automatico
    for (int i=0; i<x; i++){ 
        for (int j=0; j<x; j++) {
            matriz[i][j] = (int) (Math.random()*10);
        }
    }

    //Imprimir matriz original
    System.out.println("Matriz original");
    for (int i=0; i<x; i++){ 
        for (int j=0; j<x; j++){ 
            System.out.print(matriz[i][j]+" "); 
        }
        System.out.println(); 
    }

    //Imprimir diagonal principal
    System.out.print("La diagonal principal es:    ["); 
    for (int i=0; i<x; i++) 
        for (int j=0; j<x; j++){ 
            if (i == j) 
                System.out.print(matriz[i][j] +" "); 
        } 
    System.out.println("]");

    //Imprimir diagonal secundaria
    System.out.print("La diagonal secundaria es:    ["); 
    for (int i=x-1; i>=0; i--) 
        for (int j=0; j<x; j++) 
            if (x-1-i == j) 
                System.out.print(matriz[i][j] +" "); 
    System.out.println("]"); 

    Arrays.sort(matriz);
                                      //Esta parte es donde me tira el error
    for(int[] s : matriz)
        System.out.println(s);

    //Matriz ordenada de menor a mayor
    System.out.println("Matriz ordenada de forma ascendente");
    for (int i=0; i<x; i++){ 
        for (int j=0; j<x; j++){ 
            System.out.print(matriz[i][j]+" "); 
        }
        System.out.println(); 
    }
 }
}
```

El error es:

```
Ingrese la dimension de la matriz: 
3

9 3 7 
7 1 8 
0 5 6 

La diagonal principal es:    [9 1 6 ]
La diagonal secundaria es:    [0 1 7 ]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [I cannot be cast 
to java.lang.Comparable
at
java.util.ComparableTimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(ComparableTimSort.java:320 
 )
at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:188)
at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1246)
at Matriz.main(Matriz.java:43)
C:\Users\José Padrón\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor- 
snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 3 seconds)
```

Comment: perfecto. Elimina tu comentario ya que no hace falta ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es más fácil visualizar un arreglo de dos dimensiones si lo imaginas cómo uno de una dimensión, pero cada uno de sus elementos contiene otro arreglo.
Por ejemplo, para arreglar tu código puedes hacer esto:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Matriz{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] matriz = new int[10][10];

    //añade valores al arreglo
    for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++){ 
        for (int j=0; j< matriz[i].length; j++) {
            matriz[i][j] = (int) (Math.random()*10);
        }
    }

    //accede a cada arreglo dentro de la matriz y lo pasas a la función sort que solo admite arreglos de una dimensión.
    for(int[] i: matriz){
        Arrays.sort(i);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta es algo simple, `Arrays.sort()` sólo sirve para arreglos de una dimensión, lo que sí puedes hacer, entendiendo que un arreglo de 2 dimensiones es como si cada en una de las posiciones de un arreglo unidimensional hubiese otro arreglo unidimensional, es hacer un `Arrays.sort()` de por ejemplo matriz[1], matriz[2],... hasta la ultima posición y luego ordenarla en base al dato de matriz[1][1], matriz[2][1],... hasta la última posición igualmente

Es decir:

```
 for(int i=0;i<matriz.length;i++) Arrays.sort(matriz[i]);
```

y luego por el método de tu preferencia ordenar el arreglo en base a los datos de las posiciones [k][1] del arreglo, con k = {0,1,2,3....,matriz.length-1}.